# Issue Using jDDE to connect Java to Excel

Tags: java, excel, dde

I tried writing a sample code - the simplest possible, I'm getting a connection error.

```
package my.excel.dde;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.code.jdde.client.ClientConversation;
import com.google.code.jdde.client.DdeClient;

public class ExcelDdeExperiment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filepath = "C:\\temp\\workbook1.xls";
        final String sheetname = "Sheet1";
        final DdeClient ddeclient = new DdeClient();
        ClientConversation conversation = null;
        String filename = null;

        try {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            File file = new File(filepath);
            desktop.edit(file);
            filename = file.getName();

            conversation = ddeclient.connect(filename, sheetname);
            if (conversation != null) {
                System.out.println("successfully connected");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot open excel file: " + filepath, e);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot connect to excel file: " + filename, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot connect to excel file: workbook1.xls
    at com.bfm.app.ldi.client.excel.dde.ExcelDdeExperiment.main(ExcelDdeExperiment.java:35)
Caused by: com.google.code.jdde.misc.DdeException: [DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED] A client's attempt to establish a conversation has failed.
    at com.google.code.jdde.ddeml.constants.DmlError.throwExceptionIfValidError(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.code.jdde.client.DdeClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.bfm.app.ldi.client.excel.dde.ExcelDdeExperiment.main(ExcelDdeExperiment.java:28)
```

I tried first passing the full filepath to

```
conversation = ddeclient.connect(filename, sheetname);
```

then I tried passing only the filename, in both cases it didn't work.

Anyone has can point me in the right direction?

Kind Regards

Comment: You ever get to the bottom of this?  The file opens great with the code above, but the expected first parameter of the connect method is a service name running on a server.  Did you have a service running or were you just working with a local excel file?

Comment: this worked for me - I had to change the filename I think, can't remember

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use another library, for example, library with the same name (JDDE) from http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/. You can find examples at the website.